# Fade in an animated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a div thats slides down when the page loads but I can not figure out how to have it fade in as it animates. I tried different fadIn effects but nothing seems to work.

```
  $(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
  $("#headerWrapper").animate({top: '+=200px'}, 1000).fadeIn();
      }, function() {
  $("#headerWrapper").animate({top: '-=100%'}, 1000).fadeIn();
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oq83qc7o/

Comment: Can you help us to help you and share your jsfiddle :-) ?

Comment: Have you tried this with a slideDown instead of animate?

Comment: You can use the `.animate()` callback: http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete

Comment: So much depends on the styling you really need to provide code, HTML and style (for which a JSFiddle is great) :)

Comment: fiddle is attached @mpacheco

Comment: yeah I did the div did not move down the way I would like it @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob

Comment: It works fine if you use the `callback`. I've just changed to `.fadeOut()` to make it clear. http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/oq83qc7o/1/

Comment: Also, `.fadeIn()` will work just with elements that are _invisible_ when called.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work with what I am try to do. I need to to fade in while it animates down @MelanciaUK

Comment: So you should edit your question to explain it better.

Comment: @mpacheco have you seen the new code snippets http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also animate the opacity. So set it to 0 to begin with then when the animate runs it will change it to 1 over the period of the animation;

```
 $(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
  $("#headerWrapper").animate({top: '0px', opacity: 1}, 1000);
      }, function() {
  $("#headerWrapper").animate({top: '-=100%', opacity: 1}, 1000);
 });
```

Also has to change some of your CSS:

```
section#headerWrapper {
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index:1;
    padding-bottom:1em;
    top:-80px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

[See this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/oq83qc7o/5/)

Answer (score -1):

The answer of David Jones is correct. But I'll add a couple of things to his answer.

The reason why your function is not working the way you want it to is because of jQuery's chaining feature. If you add another function to your initial jQuery object it executes the functions in order of invoking.

Example

```
$('#myObject').animate().fadeIn()
```

will execute animate() first, then wait for it to finish and execute fadeIn()

**CSS**

```
#headerWrapper {
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;

    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
    padding-bottom:1em;
    /* margin-top:-200px; unnecessary for fixed positioned elements */

    top: -200px;
}
```

**JS (from David Jones answer)**

```
$(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
    $("#headerWrapper").animate({top: '+=200px', opacity: 1}, 1000);
}, function() {
    $("#headerWrapper").animate({top: '-=100%', opacity: 1}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I don't think you added anything...you just restated everything David Jones already said...you also don't even know if OP wants absolute positioning at the coordinates (0,0)

Comment: Please review my answer. I explained a bit about jQuery chaining.

Comment: does not work because my position needs to be a fixed position @だらんぎんじょん